# Data structure for stacked intervals

Tags: data-structures, stack, lookup, intervals

I have a list of items with integral widths, which can be interpreted as intervals stacked together from left to right. For example, say the items are A,B,C,D,E and F and have widths 5,2,2,3,2 and 4 respectively:

[image: Example]

The numbers below items indicate offsets from the start of the list.

I am looking for a data structure which efficiently supports those operations, ideally in less than O(n):

- Find an item from at a given position. For example, the item at position 11 is D since it spans from 9 to 12, and the item at position 14 is F since it starts there.
- Insert an item between any two existing items, or remove any existing item. This should shift the position of subsequent items. For example, removing item E should cause item F to shift left two positions so it would then span from 12 to 16.

I was thinking of using something similar to a skip list, with each level storing the width it encompasses in the level below, but I'm not too sure about what performance characteristics I could get.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about a variant of the [rope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_%28data_structure%29).

But instead of having strings at the leaves, it has intervals.

Finding the interval containing a particular position would be O(log n) (just modify the indexing algorithm of the rope to return the leaf instead of indexing into it).

Inserting an item anywhere would be O(log n) (by splitting once and concatenating twice, all of which take O(log n)).

Unlike in a skiplist, which is probabilistic in nature and has O(n) worst cases if you run into some bad luck, those operations would be O(log n) guaranteed (assuming you use the O(log n) balancing-concatenate).

Comment: Ahhh, I knew this could be expressed in terms of a well-known data structure! Very elegant.